Performing a sum of a calculated column in SQL Server
I need to write a SQL query that adds a new calculated column from  existing columns in the table.
The existing columns are: ProductInv, IntCantInv and SalCantInv.
The calculated column is called DIF.
I need to add the entire calculated column DIF. Is there any way to do it?
Here is my SQL query that works well:
SELECT 
    ProductInv, IntCantInv, SalCantInv, 
    (IntCantInv - SalCantInv) AS DIF 
FROM 
    TABLA_MOVIMIENTO_INVENTARIOS 
WHERE
    ProductInv = 10001001008


Thank you very much for your help.

It's not clear what you're asking for.

What's wrong with what you have? If any of the original values change, then your calculated field will be invalid

Do you mean you want to add another row with a total sum? SQL Server is not excel, so you shouldn't do this normally, but check out GROUPING SETS perhaps

I think what you're trying to do is sum the differences, but it's not clear. If that interpretation is correct, you can do this:
SELECT SUM(EntCantInv-SalCantInv) AS TotalDIF 
FROM TABLA_MOVIMIENTO_INVENTARIOS 
Where ProductInv=10001001008

For the sample data, that would give you this result:



TotalDIF




59




I really liked this solution and it works perfectly.
Thank you very much genius

Here's a couple of variations which might be useful to you:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (10001001008, 636, 1251)
    ,   (10001001008, 920, 928)
    ,   (10001001008, 992, 1033)
    ,   (10001001008, 1051, 1241)
    ,   (10001001008, 1218, 1143)
    ,   (10001001008, 1271, 1137)
    ,   (10001001008, 1273, 1470)
    ,   (10001001008, 1291, 1331)
    ,   (10001001008, 1345, 1780)
    ,   (10001001008, 1414, 864)
    ,   (10001001008, 2087, 1261)
) t (Productoinv,EntCantinv,SalCantInv)

SELECT  Productoinv, ISNULL(EntCantinv, 0) AS EntCantinv, ISNULL(SalCantInv, 0) AS SalCantInv, SUM(EntCantinv - SalCantInv) AS Dif
FROM    #data
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Productoinv, EntCantinv,SalCantInv),(Productoinv))

SELECT  Productoinv, EntCantinv, SalCantInv, EntCantinv - SalCantInv Dif, SUM(EntCantinv - SalCantInv) OVER(PARTITION BY Productoinv) AS TotalDif
FROM    #data

First one adds a new summary row, while second adds a new column containing summarized value.
